# List reports with crystal report C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I've created a report with crystal report. I fetch data using `ReportObjects.`
When I try to use it with one object, it works fine. But I don't know how to use it with several data.

Here is my code

```
//I get here the user

UserReport _usRep = new UserReport();
Section body = _usRep.Section1;

TextObject _name = (TextObject)body.ReportObjects["name"];
TextObject _surname = (TextObject)body.ReportObjects["surname "];
TextObject _age = (TextObject)body.ReportObjects["age"];

_name.Text = _user.Name;
_surname.Text = _user.surname;
_age.Text = _user.age+"";

crystal_view.ViewerCore.ReportSource = _usRep;
```

Here is my `User` model definition

```
   public class User{
     public string name{get; set;}
     public string surname{get; set;}
     public int age{get; set;}
   }
```

Comment: i am not familiar what a crystal report is
maybe could you explain in a more general fashion what you are trying to do and what the crystal report is for? maybe we can provide you a better solution

Comment: It used for making reporting by ''connecting it to the app database.''. What I'm looking for is the way to create a list of the same designed view via crystal report. The post above  can accept one data while I want to send several data to repeat the same view with different contents

Comment: @DenisSchaf Read the tag info: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crystal-reports/info